# Can someone explain how the following equations come to be in the Cosmological Pertrubation Theory?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, perturbation-theory

I'm just starting out studying the Cosmological Perturbation Theory and most of the things do NOT make sense to me. For example, how these two equations came to be. Please, also mention some starting points I should keep in mind to understand this subject better. [image]

Comment: These are the two independent Einstein equations for scalar perturbations to the metric.

Comment: What do you mean how the equations came to be? If you mean how can one obtain them, then it's clearly mentioned in the text - from the $(ij)$ and $(00)$ components of Einstein's equations linearized to first order.